# Capture media key events in a browser

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, keyboard

Many keyboards have media control keys on them these days: Play/Pause, Next, Previous, etc.

[image: Media keys]

*I'm not talking about F1-F12 keys here, btw*

Is it possible to capture and react to keypresses on these media keys in webpage in a browser? My rudimentary tests show that they don't fire the keypress event on the `window` object.

A built-in solution would obviously be great, but for my situation, even an extension would be ok. Is it possible to write a Firefox/Chrome plugin that would do this?

Comment: Check if these keys fire the `keydown` event. If not, you are most likely out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, they don't, but I'm not limiting myself to the DOM and Javascript: What about writing a browser extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, [some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API#browser_compatibility) has [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API) to handle **some**  of the Media key events.

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() { /* Do something */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() { /* Do something */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Do something */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Do something */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() { /* Do something */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() { /* Do something */ });
```

The current playback state can be also be accessed using [playbackState accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession/playbackState), i.e.

```
navigator.mediaSession.playbackState; //"paused" or "playing"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is doable and has already been done http://smus.com/chrome-media-keys/
Maybe he'll share the source code with you