# Extend browsers to handle Apple keyboard events

Tags: javascript, browser, keyboard, dom-events

Is there any way to extend browsers (e.g., Google Chrome) to handle input events from non-standard keyboards? Consider an Apple keyboard, there are special keys like Play/Pause (usually on <kbd>F8</kbd>). Can we capture inputs from those keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question here: [Capture media key events in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600337/capture-media-key-events-in-a-browser)

These keys do not fire events in browsers, but there is an extension for Chrome which seems to add this functionality:
http://smus.com/chrome-media-keys/

Comment: `These keys do not fire events in browsers` - I think you are wrong on that one. The extension itself merely uses `window.onkeydown`. See it here: https://github.com/borismus/Chrome-Media-Keys/blob/master/key.js

Comment: Interesting, I just checked and the apple media keys do not fire those events. Either this extension doesn't work with apple media keys or I'm missing something.

Comment: So the keycodes it's listening for are the function keys, not the media keys. The media keys do not fire events, but the function keys do (fn+f8 on a mac, for example)

Comment: So basically, the main problem is that every keyboard will fire different events. Doesn't sound good to me.